# Multiple action contexts in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to Zend and am working on a project that requires three contexts for a particular action. There is the standard context that will normally be used, an AJAX context for AJAX calls, and finally a print-friendly context. The goal is for each of these to have their own view, so the view files used would be something like:

/action_name.phtml
/action_name.ajax.phtml
/action_name.print.phtml

I read http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html and came up with:

```
public function init()
{
    // add any necessary context switching here
    $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $contextSwitch->addActionContext('history', 'html')
        ->initContext();
    //need to add another context for the print view
    $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch')->addActionContext('history','print')->initContext();
}
```

The first two lines I am convinced works, but I am not sure if I am going about the print context the right way, since in the examples the second parameter is normally a file type, like JSON, XML, HTML, etc. Am I going about things the right way or is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's everything in the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.custom). If you want custom contexts, you have to add them first:

```
$this->_helper
     ->getHelper('contextSwitch')
     ->addContext('print', array(
           // context options go here
       ))
     ->addActionContext('history', 'print')
     // more addActionContext()s goes here
     ->initContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might do instead of using a context for the print view is just have a parameter in the URL like `/print/1`. Then in the controller action, check to see if that parameter is true, and if it is, render the "print" view script instead of the regular view script.